# Android: Two images inside a scroll view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I would like to be able to display 2 images to a user, however I would like the images to fill the screen (horizontally) and then be able to scroll down to the next image, is this possible? I have been messing around with different XML layouts and cant seem to find a solution. 
When I place an image view inside of a scroll view it doesn't fill the screen, how can I get 2 in there but only 1 visible to start off with?

```
 ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/building_block"
    android:layout_margin="2dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_ntm"
            android:id="@+id/imageView15" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_ntm"
            android:id="@+id/imageView17"
            android:layout_marginTop="44dp" />

    </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

That is what I would like but is it possible. 1 image under the other each filling the screen and in a scrollview?

Comment: To be able to help can you paste your layout code, it will be easier that way.

Comment: @Ashwin I have updated the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant add more than on child to a ScrollView (or HorizontalScrolView).

You can fix it with a child layout to have both elements.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_ntm"
        android:id="@+id/imageView15" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_ntm"
        android:id="@+id/imageView17"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp" />
     </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Also note the             android:layout_weight="1", so each ImageView can take half of the view, cause if both are fill_parent only the first will show.

Comment: Hi, thanks after adjusting the stray /> for the linearLayout this is working, is there a way to stretch the image to the size of the screen?

Comment: scaleType is not working? The image should be the size of the view

Answer (score 0):

I think I need to set your images height programmatically to be equal with screen height.

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="800dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="800dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: No do not do this. This will not work for different screens.

Comment: PROGRAMATICLY - means to set from code.  of course android:layout_height="800dp" will not work for different screens. DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        findViewById(image_view_id).setHeight( metrics.heightPixels );

Comment: Sorry I was just looking at your code sample. I am always cautious about programmatically determined layout sizes. Its better to let the OS determine the correct size, especially when trying to fill the entire space. There is no need to use the code in your comment as you can set the weight and scale type in the layout file. Using just the layout file is much easier to maintain.